# How do I calculate the value of information gain in order to reduce the floating-point approximation errors?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy, numerical-methods

I have a dataset containing some features that belong to two class labels denoted by *1* and *2*. This dataset is procedded in order to build a decision tree: during the construction of the tree, I need to calculate the information gain to find the best partitioning of the dataset.

Let there be *N1* features associated to label *1*, and *N2* features associated to label *2*, then the **entropy** can be calculated with the following formula:

`Entropy = - (N1/N)*log2(N1/N) - (N2/N)*log2(N2/N)`, where *N = N1 + N2*

I need to calculate three values of entropy in order to obtain the information gain:

- `entropyBefore`, that is the entropy before the partitioning of the current dataset;
- `entropyLeft`, that is the entropy of the left split after the partitioning;
- `entropyRight`, that is the entropy of the right split after the partitioning.

So, the information gain is equal to `entropyBefore - (S1/N)*entropyLeft - (S2/N)*entropyRight`, where *S1* is the number of the features of class *1* belonging to the split 1, and *S2* is the number of the features of class *2* belonging to the split 2.

How do I calculate the value of information gain in order to reduce the floating-point approximation errors? When I apply the above formulas in those cases in which the information gain must be zero, however the calculated value is equal to a very small negative value.

**UPDATE** (sample code)

```
double N = static_cast<double>(this->rows());   // rows count of the dataset

double entropyBefore = this->entropy();   // current entropy (before performing the split)

bool firstCheck = true;
double bestSplitIg;

for each possible split
{
    // ...

    pair<Dataset,Dataset> splitPair = split(...,...);
    double S1 = splitPair.first.rows();
    double S2 = splitPair.second.rows();

    double entropyLeft = splitPair.first.entropy();
    double entropyRight = splitPair.second.entropy();

    double splitIg = entropyBefore - (S1/N*entropyLeft + S2/N*entropyRight);
    if (firstCheck || splitIg > bestSplitIg)
    {
        bestSplitIg = splitIg;
        // ...

        firstCheck = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: well not using floating point to do it, was my first thought.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Please explain what better way you propose to calculate log2 without floating point.

Comment: Please show a [short, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org) with both code and data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Same way as you do it with floats but a different representation for the result, such as Decimal. Was that a trick question?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: A different representation does not solve the problem. People commonly suggest decimal for working with currency, but that works only because the values involved are commonly even decimal amounts. These formulas involving logarithms will be irregular in any representation, so there will be rounding errors in any representation.

Comment: So you choose a level of precision that results in a tolerable level of innaccuracy. Choosing a Fixed point repesentation removes all the inaccuracies inherrent in floating point representations. Seeing as the numbers involved are irrational, that's all you can do, short of being good it enough at math to come up with an alternative formulation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using entropy to determine which alternative is better, so that you only need the result of comparing two entropies and do not need their actual values, then you can eliminate some calculations.

You have this function: Entropy(N1, N2, N) -> - N1/N*log2(N1/N) - N2/N*log2(N2/N).

Supposing that N is a constant for the duration of your problem, let’s multiply the expression by N:

> - N1*log2(N1/N)-N2*log2(N2/N)

Next, separate the “/N” out of the logarithms:

> - N1*(log2(N1)-log2(N)) - N2*(log2(N2)-log2(N))

and expand:

> - N1*log2(N1) - N2*log2(N2) - (N1+N2)*log2(N)

and simplify:

> - N1*log2(N1) - N2*log2(N2) - N*log2(N)

Clearly N*log2(N) is a constant and does not affect whether one entropy is greater than another so we can discard it.

Also, multiply by ln(2), which also does not change whether one entropy is greater than another. This has the effect of changing the log2 functions to ln functions, and ln may be calculated slightly more accurately by the math library (there is a reason it is the “natural” logarithm):

> E(N1, N2, N) -> - N1*ln(N1) - N2*ln(N2)

This function has fewer operations, so it may be computed more accurately than the Entropy function, and it has the property that (when calculated exactly) E(N1, N2, N) < E(M1, M2, N) iff Entropy(N1, N2, N) < Entropy(M1, M2, N).

Comment: Well, I should compare two values of information gain, so I should repeat your procedure on the formula used to calculate the information gain.